# Flutter - Convert json string to json object

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization

I have a json string like this: `

```
"{"facility_id":45,"block_id":74,"permit_id":0,"assigned_id":51,"title":"woo","description":"egg ugh oh blower Rd","status":2,"createdBy":"","AssetsIds":[{"asset_id":15236,"category_ids":4},{"asset_id":15232,"category_ids":4}],"WorkType_Ids":[]}"`
```

When I send this to the API, I get a 415 error (unsupported format).

The same thing without the external quotes, works (in postman):
[image]

Now I understand that I need to do a json.decode(str)
; but that doesn't work either. I still get the same error. How do i send this data in the correct format?

EDIT

```
            var responseModel = await apiWrapper.makeRequest(
          'Job/CreateNewJob?job=$job',
          Request.post,
          null, //job,
          isLoading ?? true,
          {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $auth',
          },
        );
```

This part is causing the error, most certainly there is an issue with the headers.

Comment: How do you send the string to the API?

Comment: Could you please provide further information regarding the error you are currently encountering, along with a sample of the code used to make the request?

Comment: And could you share a larger screenshot of how it works in Postman? I would imagine the job is expected in the response body. Your flutter code sends it as part of the URl which seems weird

Comment: Thank you for your time guys, turns out in my code I was sending the body as body: json.encode(data); just needed to remove the json.encode part and it ran succuessfully.